# choose Jenkins post actions agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to choose where the post build actions will be executed?

```
pipeline {
    agent windows

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    
    post {
      // agent linux
      always { 
            echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run the post build actions on linux agent is there a way todo that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to do could be achieved like that:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'linux' }
    stages {
        stage('Setup Agent') {
            agent { label 'windows' }
            stages {
                stage('Hello') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Hello World'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
        }
    }
}
```

then the post will run on the agent from the top and the inner stages will run on the inner agent.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a declarative pipeline

```
post {
    always {
        node('linux') {
            echo 'I will always say Hello again!'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That only run the step inside the post in different node the post itself stays in the same node.

Comment: And what would be the problem with that? The post build actions will be a set of 'scripts' executed on linux agent.

Comment: I need the post action to release the node it acquires now, so if it still run there it does not release it.

Comment: Ahh, I see...What about using linux agent on the pipeline level and setting windows on the stage level where needed?

Comment: That could work but that means setting it on each step... and I have many.